# SQL From the same table find records shared by common criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

**DB: postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.16 (Ubuntu 10.16-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)**

I have a table `device_clients` in which following data is present:

| id | device_id | client_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 | 3 |
| 11 | 1 | 4 |
| 12 | 2 | 2 |
| 13 | 2 | 3 |
| 14 | 2 | 4 |
| 15 | 3 | 2 |
| 16 | 3 | 3 |
| 17 | 3 | 4 |

I need to find out devices common between **each** client I provide. For e.g. following are the devices for each client

```
Client-1 => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
Client-2 => 1, 2, 3
Client-3 => 1, 2, 3
Client-4 => 1, 2, 3
```

So for clients 1, 2, 3 the common devices expected are 1, 2, 3.

Can anybody please help me formulate an efficient query to achieve the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  For instance:

```
select device_id
from t
where client_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by device_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

For convenience, you can pass the list of clients in as an array, allowing you to use:

```
select device_id
from t
where client_id = any(:client_ar)
group by device_id
having count(*) = cardinality(:client_ar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join the table three times:

```
select a.device_id
from device_clients a
join device_clients b on b.device_id = a.device_id
join device_clients c on c.device_id = a.device_id
where a.client_id = 1
  and b.client_id = 2
  and c.client_id = 3
```